# Can a mixture of normals be a constant?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> ***Q***. Can a mixture of a finite number of 2-dimensional normal distributions,
>   with different means and covariances, sum to a constant within some
>   bounded region of the plane?

---

[image]

---

I believe the answer is *No*, in any dimension, but I have not proved that,
and I hold out some hope that a clever mixture would magically sum to a constant...

I would also be interested if the answer is *Yes* for any of the commonly
used probability distributions: Poisson, gamma, etc.

Comment: I think it is impossible. I think to prove that it is not possible globally is easy. But regionally, I am not sure, tough I have an idea. One can write down the sum of the densities, say for $10$ of then and let the constant level be $0.5$ and the region be around $0$. Then one can find the parameters of all densities such that the mean squared error is minimized. I dont know if there is an efficient algorithm in this case. Whatever, one will then see that MMSE will not be zero and adding another density will decrease MMSE.

Comment: Before I saw Poisson mentioned, I thought you meant constant density function. For continuous densities, I think you could get close enough to a constant for some practical applications, but never exactly constant. One the line a mixture of two normals (equal SDs) with nearly the same mean can have an almost flat mode between the means. Even POIS(2) has a 'double mode' at 1 & 2, so in a multivariate situation you could probably find patches of a few nearby grid points where all probabilities are equal.